# Media Queries happening before WebView is fully inflated

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, android-webview, media-queries

When testing our media equerries in Chrome everything seems to work fine, but in my app's WebView (on Android, so it is Chrome based) it reports a height of 0px, and therefore landscape orientation no matter the actual device position. As I said, this isn't an issue with Chrome. How can I change my code in order to have a real height before the media query fires?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the height of the WebView from wrap_content to 0dp in the XML layout fixed this issue. If someone with more low level knowledge of Android than I possess understands why that is, I would love to find out!